# Call delete on std::vector

Tags: c++11, stdvector

Do I have to call delete on the destructor of a class that uses std::vectors ?
If not, why?

For example:

Test.h:

```
class Test
{
private:
    // Signal buffer for RAW signal and Moving Average
    std::vector<double> BUFFER; // Sensor signal buffer
...

}
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::~Test()
{
    // no delete for std:vector as they use STD memory allocation ???
}

Test::Test()
{
    BUFFER.reserve(100); // Who is going to free this memory?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not need to explicitly destroy or delete it.  The vector is held by value in your class, so will be destroyed automatically, and the data inside the vector will be deleted by the vector's own destructor.

The term for all this is RAII, and it works really well.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. You only use `delete` to match a use of `new`. Since (in this case) you used auto storage class, the `vector` will be deleted automatically when the `Test` that owns it is destroyed.